# SSRS Difference Column between Colums in table when grouping on year

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

[Show Report - Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DZGK.jpg) In my query I have a year field, and I have column grouping on it. I have row grouping on Product group, Product section, and item. If there are no sales in a section for this year and sales were $214 last year, my difference column for that section shows $214 not ($214). Mind you, no sales equal no data in the database, so this year sales is a null value in the report.

This is my expression that I am using, however it is not working:

```
=IIF(
     ISNothing(Sum(IIF(Fields!Year.Value = MAX(Fields!Year.Value),
                       1,
                       0) * Fields!Subtotal.Value)) = True,
     -1 * (Sum(IIF(Fields!Year.Value = Min(Fields!Year.Value),
                   1,
                   0) * Fields!Subtotal.Value)),
     Sum(IIF(Fields!Year.Value = Max(Fields!Year.Value),
             Fields!Subtotal.Value,
             -1 * Fields!Subtotal.Value))
)
```

Comment: How is it "not working"? what is the precise expected behaviour and the actual result when this executes?

Comment: I added a link to a image of the report. Thanks Jonnus.

Comment: What's the format for that cell currently?

Comment: And are you returning null from the database, or 0 (as 0 is the figure that appears in the 2015 data column)

Comment: This is the expression for sales: =IIF(ISNOTHING(Sum(Fields!Subtotal.Value)) = TRUE, 0, Sum(Fields!Subtotal.Value))

Comment: Null is being returned because there is no data whatsoever. If I were to just query stock cabinets for 2015, there would be no rows returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I used this for my expression:

```
=IIF(MAX(Fields!Year.Value)<> MAX(Parameters!Year.Value(0)), Sum(IIF(Fields!Year.Value = Max(Fields!Year.Value), Fields!Subtotal.Value, -1*Fields!Subtotal.Value))*-1, Sum(IIF(Fields!Year.Value = Max(Fields!Year.Value), Fields!Subtotal.Value, -1*Fields!Subtotal.Value)))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know your problem is generated in this expression:

```
Sum(IIF(Fields!Year.Value = Max(Fields!Year.Value),
             Fields!Subtotal.Value,
             -1 * Fields!Subtotal.Value))
```

You mentioned in comments there is no rows for `Stock Cabinets` in 2015 so the maximum year value is 2014 for that group.

Try using this:

```
Sum(IIF(Fields!Year.Value = Today.Year,
             Fields!Subtotal.Value,
             -1 * Fields!Subtotal.Value))
```

It will work if your maximum year is the current calendar year. `Today.Year` takes the current calendar year of the system at runtime.

**UPDATE:** I tried to create a minimal and verificable example of your problem.

This is the dataset I've used.

```
select 10 Value, 2015 [Year], 'Otro' Category
union all
select 20 Value, 2015 [Year], 'Otro' Category
union all
select 30 Value, 2015 [Year], 'Otro' Category
union all
select 10 Value, 2014 [Year], 'Otro' Category
union all
select 7 Value, 2014[Year], 'Stock Cabinets' Category
union all
select 3 Value, 2014 [Year], 'Stock Cabinets' Category
```

I used the same expression in my total column, the today.Year expression is the only change I made.

```
=IIF(
    ISNothing(Sum(IIF(Fields!Year.Value = max(Fields!Year.Value),
                       1,
                       0) * Fields!Value.Value)) = True,
     -1 * (Sum(IIF(Fields!Year.Value = Min(Fields!Year.Value)
     ,1
     ,0) * Fields!Value.Value)),
    Sum(IIF(Fields!Year.Value = Today.Year,
             Fields!Value.Value,
             -1 * Fields!Value.Value))
)
```

In a matrix I set this data arrangement:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: There is only one dataset providing the report with information in the tablix. By setting the scope to that dataset, the results will be the same.

Comment: I tried it too, it still does not work (I had to change your Field!Value back to Field!Subtotal.... Was version of Visual Studio/SQL are you on? I am on 2008r2

Comment: I did create a dataset, that replicated yours, and got it to work. I just don't understand why it is not working with my data.

Comment: Are you getting the same results with my code or what do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: I figured it out. I used this for my expression. =IIF(MAX(Fields!Year.Value)<> MAX(Parameters!Year.Value(0)),
Sum(IIF(Fields!Year.Value = Max(Fields!Year.Value), Fields!Subtotal.Value, -1*Fields!Subtotal.Value))*-1,
Sum(IIF(Fields!Year.Value = Max(Fields!Year.Value), Fields!Subtotal.Value, -1*Fields!Subtotal.Value)))